# Where does OS X store accessibility preferences?

Tags: terminal, mac

I want to check if a certain app is allowed to control my computer from the terminal. I need to check Privacy > accessibility settings to do that. How do I check-- where are accessibility settings stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The database is located at `/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db`.

To query the database from the command line, use `sqlite3`.

- You can query what access a certain app has.

  ```
  sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db \
    'select service from access where client like "com.apple.Terminal"
      and auth_value = 2;'
  ```

  ```
  kTCCServiceDeveloperTool
  kTCCServiceListenEvent
  kTCCServicePostEvent
  kTCCServiceScreenCapture
  kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles
  ```
- You can query what apps have access to a certain permission like accessibility.

  ```
  sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db \
    'select client from access where service like "kTCCServiceAccessibility"
      and auth_value = 2;'
  ```

  ```
  com.apple.AEServer
  com.apple.MobileSMS
  com.apple.dt.Xcode-Helper
  …
  ```

To perform these queries, Terminal needs full disk access (`kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles`).

Replace `auth_value = 2` with `allowed = 1` if on an older macOS like High Sierra (not sure at which point it changed between High Sierra and Big Sur).

Comment: With this I'm getting this error: ```Error: no such column: auth_value```

Comment: @210 What version of macOS are you on? This was only tested on the latest Big Sur 11.3b2.

Comment: I'm on High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: @210 Figured it out, edited answer! Sorry for the delay

Comment: Thank you so much!! And a follow up, if you use this query ```sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db \
  'select client from access where service like "kTCCServiceAccessibility"
    and allowed = 1;'
``` (the High Sierra) on Big Sur will it still work?

Comment: @210 No, the structure of the database is different